# Application to run on subdomain

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, dns, subdomain

I'm looking to create an ASP.NET web forms application which I want to run on a subdomain. I've created many websites before but not into a subdomain.

I am best achieving this with everything in a subfolder and then mapping this to the subdomain?

E.g.

```
My website (different server)  www.my-website.com
Subdomain                      www.sub.my-website.com
```

I'll be having a separate server which will run this app and the subdomain will be pointed to the new server with DNS at the host.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking. If you want to host the application on a subdomain, that's just a case of setting up the bindings in IIS. Why would you put it in a subfolder if it's in a different server?

Comment: I'm just looking for my entire application to run from a subdomain which will be on a separate server to the rest of my website. So I just create it a project as normal and the control the bindings from IIS?

Comment: Yes. From the web forms applications perspective, it makes no difference if it's running on a subdomain.